# Where condition in LinqDataSource for string in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linqdatasource

I am trying to populate data in `gridview` by using `LinqDataSource` and in the `where` condition of  LinqDataSource1 - programmatically I am not sure about the syntax on how to pass a string value to a particular column?

What is the syntax for where condition in `LinqDataSource` on a string programmatically?

I am familiar with the one in int:

```
 int id = 5;
```

for example:

```
LinqDataSource1.Where = "ID =" +id;
```

But, not sure about the syntax for `string`.

Please suggest something!

Comment: Can you please show the context of your question with relevant code?  It is very difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the syntax for string in LinqDataSource:

LinqDataSource1.Where = "Title.Contains("+ "\"" + txtTitle.Text + "\""+ ")";